# How can remove the null values?

Tags: null, ssas, mdx

How can I remove the null values in the bottomcount, ie. i only want to see the products with actually sold units, I have tried with nonempty and non empty without success.

```
with
member [Measures].[Amount Sold] as
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]),
format_string = "currency"

select {[Measures].[Amount Sold]}
on columns,
bottomcount(
order(

{[Product].[Product].Members},
([Measures].[Amount Sold]), bdesc),
5 )on rows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter [Product].Members using `NOT ISEMPTY()` to exclude all the empty values, and then bottomcount the filtered set.

```
with member [Measures].[Amount Sold] as
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]),
    format_string = "currency"
select 
    {[Measures].[Amount Sold]} on columns,
    order(
        bottomcount(
            filter({[Product].[Product].Members}, NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[Amount Sold])),
            5,
            [Measures].[Amount Sold]),
        [Measures].[Amount Sold], bdesc) on rows
from [Adventure Works]
```

Note that `BottomCount()` will do an ascending, break-hierarchies sort, so you need to do the `Order()` on top of it if you want descending order.

Comment: It removes the null values but doesn´t hide the ones with 0.00 in sold amount?

Comment: i solved it, just added one more statement inside the filter function: not isempty([Measures].[Fakturerat belopp]) and [Measures].[Fakturerat belopp] > 0)